# How do you use an array returned from a function in another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have this:

```
class Card {
  constructor(rank, suit){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  buildDeck(){
     //builds my deck
    return deck;
  }

  shuffleDeck(){
    //use buildDeck.deck inside here???
  }

}
```

How would I use the deck built inside `buildDeck()` inside `shuffleDeck()`?

I don't want to set globals because they are messy and not good practice

Comment: `shuffleDeck(){ var deck = this.buildDeck(); ... }`

Comment: Why are functions that deal with whole decks in a class that represents a single card?

Comment: Create a variable `deck` in `this` and use it in both function. This will allow you to use `var c = new Card(); c.buildDeck(); c.shuffleDeck()`

Comment: You should have a separate `class Deck` that represents a deck of cards, and it would then have a `cards` property that contains an array of `Card` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The methods are in the same class, so you can refer to them by this.
It's simple:

```
shuffleDeck(){
    var deck = this.buildDeck();
}
```